# How to assign an existing ElasticIP to a NAT in a VPC with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, nat

I have some whitelisted ElasticIPs that I am trying to use as the IPs for the NAT Gateways in my VPC for Lambda functions.

My VPC config looks like this:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "lambda-vpc"
  cidr = "11.0.0.0/16"

  azs                 = ["ap-southeast-2b", "ap-southeast-2c"]
  private_subnets     = ["11.0.1.0/24", "11.0.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets      = ["11.0.0.0/24"]
  enable_nat_gateway  = true
  external_nat_ip_ids = ["eipalloc-03092d9e4de71d859", "eipalloc-03092d9e4de71d859"]
}
```

But this results in the NAT gateways creating their own ElasticIPs as opposed to using the existing ones that are whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the module [docs](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc), `reuse_nat_ips` option should be used in combination with `external_nat_ip_ids`:

> reuse_nat_ips - Should be true if you **don't want EIPs to be created** for your NAT Gateways and will **instead pass them** in via the 'external_nat_ip_ids' variable

So, assuming that everything else is correct in your code:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "lambda-vpc"
  cidr = "11.0.0.0/16"

  azs                 = ["ap-southeast-2b", "ap-southeast-2c"]
  private_subnets     = ["11.0.1.0/24", "11.0.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets      = ["11.0.0.0/24"]
  enable_nat_gateway  = true

  reuse_nat_ips       = true
  external_nat_ip_ids = ["eipalloc-03092d9e4de71d859", "eipalloc-03092d9e4de71d859"]
}
```